# How do I reduce a bidimensional array to unidimensional in python?

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array a = [[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]].
How could I reduce it to b = [1,2,3]?

Comment: Are the values in the inner lists always identical? i.e. `[x, x]`? If yes, why do you even have a nested list like that?

Comment: How exactly do you want it to be reduced? Say you had a list `a = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]`, or perhaps `[[1, 2], [3], [5, 4]]`. Would you want out of these `[1, 3, 5]`, or something else?

Comment: ...if so, then the [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) `[inner_list[0] for inner_list in a]` will do the trick, but I don't know if that is indeed what you want.

Comment: the elements are always the same

Comment: a = [a[i][0] for i in range(len(a))]

Comment: `np.array(a)[:, 0]`

Answer (score 2):

If the inner array is always two of the same values.

```
a = [[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]]
b = [i for i,j in a]
```

This produces:

```
b = [1,2,3]
```

Comment: And if the inner lists can be of different lengths (but can't be empty):   `[head for head, *tail in a]`. This is especially useful for lists of generic iterables. If the elements are indexable, just `[sub[0] for sub in a]` should do.

Comment: I like that @timgeb